# Writing-mode issue on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've got following html/css code:

```
<div class="courses-edu-imm-nav-container">
<dl class="courses-edu-imm-nav">
    <dt class="active"><a title="Mentoring" href="#">Mentoring</a></dt>
    <dt><a title="Working holiday program" href="working-holiday-visa">Working holiday program</a></dt>
</dl>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.courses-edu-imm-nav-container {
  text-align:center;
}

.courses-edu-imm-nav {
  font-weight:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:left;
}

.courses-edu-imm-nav dt {
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
padding:0 2em 0 1em;
border-left:1px solid #ccc;
height:10em;
color:#000;
font-weight:'Montserrat', sans-serif!important;
font-size:0.9em;
}

.courses-edu-imm-nav a {color:#000;text-decoration:none;}

.courses-edu-imm-nav .active a {
    color:#ff4747!important;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Everything works perfectly on chrome. On Firefox - writing mode make issues in display. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/a8yeb140/

What im doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems indeed buggy for FF, one way to cure this, *if you do not intend to style `DL`*, is to use `display:contents;` which is actually understood by FF [only](http://caniuse.com/#search=contents) but should remain harmfull in this test case when understood elsewhere.

```css
.courses-edu-imm-nav-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.courses-edu-imm-nav {
  font-weight: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  display: contents;
}

.courses-edu-imm-nav dt {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 2em 0 1em;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 10em;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 'Montserrat', sans-serif!important;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.courses-edu-imm-nav a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active a {
  color: #ff4747!important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="courses-edu-imm-nav-container">
  <dl class="courses-edu-imm-nav">
    <dt class="active"><a title="Mentoring" href="#">Mentoring</a></dt>
    <dt><a title="Working holiday program" href="working-holiday-visa">Working holiday program</a></dt>
  </dl>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a8yeb140/3/

---

What is this about ? :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

> **`<display-box>`**
>
> These values define whether an element generates display boxes at all.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> Value   Description
> ```
>
> ---
>
> **`contents`**     These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes.
>
> ---
>
> **`none`**         Turns off the display of an element so that it has no effect on layout (the document is rendered as though the element did not exist). All descendant elements also have their display turned off.
>
> To have an element take up the space that it would normally take, but without actually rendering anything, use the visibility property instead.

---

Another option but understood everywhere via display might be to use the table-layout to force both element on the same line:

```css
.courses-edu-imm-nav-container {
  text-align:center;
}

.courses-edu-imm-nav {
  font-weight: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding:0;
  text-align: left;
  display: table;
  border:solid;
  background:turquoise
}


.courses-edu-imm-nav dt {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  display: table-cell;;
  padding: 0 2em 0 1em;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 10em;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 'Montserrat', sans-serif!important;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.courses-edu-imm-nav a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active a {
  color: #ff4747!important;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="courses-edu-imm-nav-container">
<dl class="courses-edu-imm-nav">
  <dt class="active"><a title="Mentoring" href="#">Mentoring</a></dt>
  <dt><a title="Working holiday program" href="working-holiday-visa">Working holiday program</a></dt>
</dl>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a8yeb140/5/

Comment: that's the case :( the full style must remain ;/

Comment: @PawełSkaba So i see no workaround, unless dl style are applued to its parent , or an extra wrapper. What kind of style is there to apply which `.courses-edu-imm-nav-container`would not be able to handle and has to be shown from `DL` ?

Comment: @PawełSkaba , i forgot about display table/table-cell , that might work .... https://jsfiddle.net/a8yeb140/5/ if that fits your styling needs